# What is the difference between `document` and `document.body`?

Tags: javascript, document

What is actually the difference between `document` and `document.body`?

For example, I have the following code:

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function(){ 
document.write('You click me!') 
})
```

```html
<div>Click anywhere</div>
```

What will be the difference if I use `document.body` instead of `document` ?

And what is actually the difference between `document` and `document.body`?

I tried to search online, but couldn't find any useful information.

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: See [Difference between document.addEventListener and window.addEventListener?](/q/12045440/4642212). The effect of binding the listener on either target is almost the same. The difference is noticable if the `<body>` doesn’t cover the entire height of the page. Otherwise the difference between an [`HTMLDocument`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument) and an [`HTMLBodyElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLBodyElement) is significant. The recommended call is probably just `addEventListener("click", () => console.log("You clicked me!"));`. Don’t use `document.write`.

Comment: You should probably read up on what the Document Object Model (DOM) is all about also

Answer (score 1):

The `document` will have all the information of your entire HTML  of a page.

The `document.body` will refer to your HTML Body.

[See the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqPRK.png)

Comment: Document isn't just the HTML.  There is a whole context and API for interactivity, location, etc.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document